# compiling directives in angular throws TypeError: $browser.cookies is not a function

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-mock

I have a directive which I'm trying to compile. It throws an error while compiling with the below error -

My directive -

```
'use strict';
/*global module*/
/*jslint unparam: true */ 
module.exports = function(app) {
  app.directive('fqClearButton', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: 'true',
    scope: {
      manager: '='
    },
    templateUrl: '/query/common/directives/templates/fq-clear-button.ejs',
    link: function(scope) {
      scope.handleClick = function() {
        scope.manager.selectedItems = [];
        scope.manager.currentPageSelected = [];
      };
    }
  };
});

};
```

Here is my jasmine test -

```
describe('clear button test', function () {
    var $rootScope, $compile

    beforeEach(module('query'));


    beforeEach(inject(function(_$compile_,_$rootScope_){
        $compile = _$compile_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;

    }));

    describe('compile directive', function () {
        var $scope;

        it('should be able to compile directive', function(){

            var markup = angular.element('<fq-clear-button></fq-clear-button>'),
                compiled; 
                scope = $rootScope.$new();

            compiled = $compile(markup)($rootScope);
            scope.$digest();

             //var element = $compile(formElement)($rootScope);
             //$rootScope.$digest();
             console.log(compiled);
             expect(compiled).toBeDefined();
        });
    });
});
```

> TypeError: $browser.cookies is not a function at sendReq 
>   (C:/WebUI/Query/app/client/public/lib/angular/angular.js:8242:24) at serverRequest 
>   (C:/WebUI/Query/app/client/public/lib/angular/angular.js:7980:16)
>           at wrappedCallback (C:/WebUI/Query/app/client/public/lib/angular/angular.js:11446:81)
>           at wrappedCallback (C:/WebUI/Query/app/client/public/lib/angular/angular.js:11446:81)
>           at C:/WebUI/Query/app/client/public/lib/angular/angular.js:11532:26
>           at Scope.$eval (C:/WebUI/Query/app/client/public/lib/angular/angular.js:12556:28)
>           at Scope.$digest (C:/WebUI/Query/app/client/public/lib/angular/angular.js:12368:31)
>           at Object. (C:/WebUI/Query/test/client/unit/common/directive/fq-clear-button-test.js:23:16)

I'm using angular - 1.2.18 and angular-mocks - 1.2.29 versions.

Please help.

Comment: For starters have you tried using compatible version of `mocks`?

Comment: This got resolved after I upgraded to angular 1.4.9 and angular-mocks 1.4.9 versions.

Answer (score 0):

This got resolved after I upgraded to angular 1.4.9 and angular-mocks 1.4.9 versions.